# Creating a Binary Search Tree visualizer using javascript css and Html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking to create a binary search tree visualizer, like in visualalgo.net in which I generate 10 random elements in javascript and those elements get used as values for the nodes to create a binary search tree. My problem is I am not able to figure out the logic for correctly positioning the elements so that it looks like a bst. For example a value smaller than the root must be placed to the left, a little to the bottom as compared to the root, wheras a larger value must be placed to the right and so on using CSS

Using javascript I created 10 random elements and created as many division HTML elements, using Javascript's method of createElement(), as the number of random Elements. The divs innerText was set to the random values by iterating through a loop.
HTML:
`<div class="elements"> </div>`

JavaScript

```
let nodeElements = document.querySelector(".elements")
const randomArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    randomArr.push(randomValue);
  }

  let newNode;
  for (let i = 0; i < randomArr.length; i++) {
    newNode = document.createElement("div");
    newNode.classList.add("node"); //To style the division to make it look like a circular node
    newNode.innerText = randomArr[i];
    nodeElements.appendChild(newNode); //node Elements is a wrapper Division encapsulating all the nodes being created in javascript 
  }
```

[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZGMv.png)